# The type 'SPFolder' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I am working on building a remote event receiver, and i added the following nuget package `Install-Package Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement -Version 15.0.0`. Then on this line of code:-

```
MetadataDefaults defaults = new MetadataDefaults("/Documents", context.Web);
```

I am getting this error:-

```
The type 'SPFolder' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'

The type 'SPWeb' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'
```

so not sure how i can fix this? i am not sure if the `Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement` can not be defined inside SharePoint online remote event receiver? because it is expecting SharePoint server-side object and not client-side object?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use that assembly from the client-side, but there is a CSOM equivalent.  The [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj164077(v=office.15)) is not as feature-complete as the server API, but it **does** have the metadata defaults that you are wanting to use.

[Nuget package here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement/).

Comment: ok i added the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement version 16.0 to my project, but on the `MetadataDefaults defaults = new MetadataDefaults("/Documents", context.Web);` i will get `The type or namespace name 'MetadataDefaults' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: You probably need to either refer to it by its full namespace `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement.MetadataDefaults = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement.MetadataDefaults()` or add a `using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement;` to the top of your class file.

Comment: did you try this at your end, because i will get this error `The type or namespace name 'MetadataDefaults' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement' (are you missing an assembly reference?)` if i define `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement.MetadataDefaults = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement.MetadataDefaults()`

Comment: Yes, although note that the parameters of the constructor for this Client version are different than what you were using, you'll want to instantiate like `new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement.MetadataDefaults(context, "/Documents")` -- but incorrect parameters would not generate a "type or namespace name does not exist" error.  This still looks like your project does not yet have a reference to that .dll.

Comment: i am not sure what is going on, but i do not think i need to add a references using Nuget. becuase even if i do not add the Nuget library, i can add a reference inside visual studio for I `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement Version 16.0.0`.. so the first point is that `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement Version 16.0.0` will be avilable inside the Reference list, but seems it does not include `MetadataDefaults`

Comment: Where did you get that .Dll from then?

Comment: when i create  any sharepoint Remote event receiver i add those libraries `Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel -Version 7.0.0`
`Install-Package Microsoft.Identity.Model.Extensions -Version 2.0.1459`
`Install-Package AppForSharePointOnlineWebToolkit -Version 3.1.5` so those will add `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement`..

Comment: Hmm, I haven't used the Toolkit package, but if you use the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM package, it includes all the CSOM .dll, and with that I am able to compile `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement.MetadataDefaults defaults = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement.MetadataDefaults(context, "/Documents");`